# Content query webpart using a calculated page field value in a filter failing

Tags: content-query-web-part

I'm having trouble getting a calculated page field (DocIdDelimited) to work as a filter value in a content query webpart. DocIdDelimited should resolve to text. I'm querying if the calculated field text is contained in another text field(RelatedDocId).

I've seen people use calculated filter values with dates, so why is this calculated field with text not working?

RelatedDocId and output type for DocIdDelimited are both single line of text.

If I create the filter with a text page field with the same content, the filter works.

[image]

This post suggests that the calculated field should be parsed as text:
http://amolmeshe.blogspot.com/2013/05/sharepoint-2013-content-query-webpart.html